# create excel file from mysqli db, and addattachment() this file to mail()

Tags: php, excel, email, phpmailer, attachment

I am able to create the excel file, it is saved in the downloads folder.
I am able to send the mail with the correct subject, body etc...
The excel file isn't attaching in the mail, please help me on this.

Edit : The AddAttachment() Statement returns false

//php code below in  tags

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';

require_once ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\excel_mailer\\PHPMailer-master\\class.phpmailer.php");

$path           =   "C:\\Users\\Manish\\Downloads";
$file_name      =   $_GET['file_name'];

$DB_server      =   "localhost";
$DB_username    =   "root";
$DB_password    =   "";
$DB_dbname      =   "timetracker";
$DB_tablename   =   "tt_users";

$conn           =   mysqli_connect ($DB_server, $DB_username, $DB_password, $DB_dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die ("Connection Failed!");
}

$sql    =   "SELECT *";
$sql    .=  " FROM $DB_tablename";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql));

else die("Couldn't execute query:<br />" . mysqli_error(). "<br />" . mysqli_errno());

$file_ending = ".xls";

$filename = $file_name.$file_ending;

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");



/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/

$sep        = "\t"; //tabbed character
$flag       = true;
$col_names  = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_insert    = "";
            foreach($row as $field=>$data) {
        if ($flag)
            $col_names      .= $field.$sep;
        if(!isset($data))
            $data_insert    .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($data != "")
            $data_insert    .= $data.$sep;
        else
            $data_insert    .= "".$sep;
    }

    if ($flag) {
        $flag       = !$flag;
        $col_names  .= "\t";
        echo (trim($col_names));
        echo "\n";
    }
    $data_insert    .= "\t";
    echo (trim($data_insert));
    echo "\n";
}

$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->From      = 'somevalid@email.address';
$email->FromName  = 'Name';
$email->Subject   = 'PFA excel file';
$email->Body      = 'Regards';
$email->AddAddress( 'somevalid@email.address' );

$file_to_attach = $path."\\".$filename;

//echo $path."\\".$filename;

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach );

$email->Send();
```

Comment: Why are you calling header()? It has nothing to do with email. You need to check your paths and also the return value from `addAttachment()`.

Comment: @Synchro header() is for the excel file. I have checked the file path.. it gets saved in the downloads folder, i have commented out an echo statement in the end of the code just to double check... The AddAttachment statement is returning false :(

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to call header() unless you're sending the excel file to the browser as well as sending via email. It has no effect on the email, that's all handed by PHPMailer. If addAttachment is returning false, your path is probably wrong or lacks permissions. Also you've based your code on an obsolete PHPMailer example and are probably using an old version. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @Synchro I just commented out the first header statement and moved the 2nd one to just before initialisation of $email.. it worked once file got attached once, but not working again :/

Comment: Didn't I make it clear? You do not need to call header() at all. It has nothing to do with email. Check everything - trying random things and hoping is not a viable debugging technique.

Comment: i want to download the excel file created and mail it.. to download the file, i need header()... I transfered the mail code to another php file and tried redirecting the page using header() at the end of excel code... It doesnt work, there is a problem with downloading and redirecting that i dont know how to tackle

Comment: No, **you do not need to call header to download the file on the server**. Header sends headers to the client browser, it has nothing to do with email or downloading on the server. You do not need to redirect either. Be logical, fix one thing at a time; you're just confusing yourself by doing random things.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exist, maybe you have an error in the path, or the file is not readable.

```
$file_to_attach = $path."\\".$filename;    
if (!file_exists ( $file_to_attach ) die ("File $file_to_attach not readable");    
else $email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach );
```

Comment: i've checked path and permissions.. all is fine there...

I think since the file is created at runtime, i cant access the file as nothing is there.. i.e. the file doesnt exist, but on re-running the program file is attached!

Comment: Where exactly you save the file $filename in disk?. what is the line?

I see the mail add the attach in "$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach );", and I see the line that define the file name "$filename = $file_name.$file_ending;", but not the line when you save de file.
Are you sure that my code don't show the die message?

Comment: it shows the die message once, but when i rerun the program, it doesnt.

Comment: So, it means that the file was created after the if/die.
The second execution found the first file...
Maybe you need make a flush, close file or something like to create the file before the if/die.